# Group by nested belongs_to association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to visualise the distribution of `QueryLeads` for `Event`. So, count the queryleads per event and then group the events according to the amount of queryleads (preferably settable bands). I was of the opinion that I could do that with the following relations:

```
Event
has_many :queries
has_many :query_leads, through: :queries

Query
belongs_to :event
has_many :query_leads

QueryLead
belongs_to :query
```

I can perform the join : `QueryLead.joins(:query => :event)` but then once I start grouping I don't seem able to group on the id of the event. `QueryLead.joins(:query => :event).group('query_leads.id','query_leads.query.events_id').count` returns a `PG::UndefinedTable Error - missing FROM-clause entry for table "query"`.

The best I can do seems to be: `.group('query_leads.id', 'query_leads.query_id')`, which is a level too low.

What am I doing wrong/how would you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This query should works for you.

```
Event.joins(queries: :query_leads).select('events.id, COUNT( query_leads.id ) as count').group('events.id')
```